# Monaco Editor: remove duplicates in completion provider for multiple editor instances

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

I currently have a language server that provides SQL autocompletion for keywords, functions, tables, columns etc...

The language server is running on the back-end and it's providing autocompletion based on the client's requests.
On the front-end I have a react app with the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
import { listen } from '@codingame/monaco-jsonrpc';
import {
    MonacoLanguageClient,
    MonacoServices,
    createConnection,
    MessageConnection,
} from "monaco-languageclient";
import ReconnectingWebSocket from "reconnecting-websocket";
import { URI } from 'vscode-uri';

const LANGUAGE_ID = 'sql';

let languageClient: MonacoLanguageClient;

class MonacoEditor extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const {
            wordWrap,
            showLineNumbers,
            readOnly,
            id
        } = this.props;
        
        // creating the editor
        this.editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById(id) as HTMLElement, {
            model: monaco.editor.createModel('', LANGUAGE_ID, monaco.Uri.parse(`inmemory://model${id}.sql`)),
            minimap: { enabled: false },
            glyphMargin: true,
            lightbulb: {
                enabled: true
            },
            language: LANGUAGE_ID,
            fontSize: 14,
            matchBrackets: 'always',
            wordWrap: wordWrap ? 'on' : 'off',
            lineNumbers: showLineNumbers ? 'on' : 'off',
            readOnly,
            scrollBeyondLastLine: false
        });

        // installing the language client
        MonacoServices.install(monaco);

        function createLanguageClient(
            connection: MessageConnection
        ): MonacoLanguageClient {
            return new MonacoLanguageClient({
                name: "SQL Language Server MonacoClient",
                clientOptions: {
                    documentSelector: ["sql"],
                    workspaceFolder: {
                        uri: URI.file('/opt/monaco_editor'),
                        name: 'workspace',
                        index: 0
                    }
                },
                connectionProvider: {
                    get: (errorHandler, closeHandler) => {
                        return Promise.resolve(
                            createConnection(connection, errorHandler, closeHandler)
                        );
                    },
                },
            });
        }

        function createWebSocket(url: string): ReconnectingWebSocket {
            const socketOptions = {
                maxReconnectionDelay: 10000,
                minReconnectionDelay: 1000,
                reconnectionDelayGrowFactor: 1.3,
                connectionTimeout: 10000,
                maxRetries: Infinity,
                debug: false,
            };
            return new ReconnectingWebSocket(url, [], socketOptions);
        }

        const URL = "ws://localhost:8080";
        const webSocket = createWebSocket(URL) as WebSocket;
        listen({
            webSocket,
            onConnection: (connection) => {
                languageClient = createLanguageClient(connection);
                const disposable = languageClient.start();
                connection.onClose(() => disposable.dispose());
            },
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { id } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>SQL Syntax checking</h1>
                <div id={id} style={{height: '600px', width: '100%' }} />
            </div>);
    }
}

export default MonacoEditor;
```

What I want to achieve is having multiple editor instances on the same page. However, when I try to do that I get duplicate keywords in the completion suggestions (see below).

I tried to do some research but I couldn't find anything that works for my case.
As you can see from the code I don't have any `monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider()` that I could dispose. All the autocompletion data is sent by the back-end.
Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this while component dismount you can, dispose the editor

```
this.editor.dispose()
```